# Mako template - setting variable

Tags: python, html, mako

I have a python module builds different charts / graphs using pyplot.  The method I'm including in my Mako template returns a string which is the absolute path to the image it produces.  I'm trying to include this image in my html site, but keep getting a syntax error with Mako.  Here is how everything looks:

mako_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%! from my_plotter import MyPlotter>
<html>
.
.
<%
    plotter = MyPlotter()
    image = plotter.build_graph()
    <img src="${image}" height="200" width="100%">
%>
.
.
</html>
```

I can call plotter.build_graph() without a problem, but as soon as I assign a variable from its returned value I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

In the tag <% %> you put only python code, you can save your image using

```
savefig('image.png')
```

and then in the html access to it with the img tag